# Error whe deploying Shiny App ""An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1""

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, deploying

I've been working on a Shiny app and locally it works fine, it displays my graphs and lets me twitch the widgets. I have 3 csv files hosted in the `data` folder, that is placed where my `app.R` and `fc_auxiliares.R` files are. I have a shinyapp.io account and check I upload everything when publishing, both the .R files and the data folder.
One of the datasets weights 160MB, the other two a hundred KBs each.

The trouble is I get the message "An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1" when deploying, using shinyapps.io.

I don't know why this rises. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code, simplified all the text in the UI.

```
# Package names
x <-c('shinydashboard','flexdashboard','shinyWidgets', 'shinythemes', 'shinyjs', 'thematic', 'glue', 'ggplot2', 'stringr',
             'connectapi', 'tidyverse', 'RColorBrewer', 'raster',  'ggmap', 'wordcloud2', 'maps',  'geosphere', 'ggmap', 
             'dplyr', 'plotly', 'sp', 'viridis') 

# Install packages not yet installed
installed_packages <- x %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_packages == FALSE)) {
    install.packages(x[!installed_packages])
}

# Packages loading
invisible(lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE))

#Load data
datos = read.csv('./data/data_aeropuertos.csv') 
datos$mes_name <- factor(datos$mes_name, levels=c('Ene', 'Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'))
datos$fecha_datetime <- factor(datos$fecha_datetime, levels=c('Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab','Dom'))
aeropuertos = read.csv('./data/aeropuertos_detalle.csv', sep=';') 
library(geojsonio)
provincias <- geojson_read("./data/provincias.json", what = "sp") 

#Helper functions 2 plot
source('fc_auxiliares.R')

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("readable"),
    titlePanel(h1("...", align="center")),
   
    fluidRow(width=12, style = "background-color: #95c2c9; padding: 10px", 
             h5('...'),
             p('....') ),
    
    
    # #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(width=12,style = "background-color: #badbe0; padding: 20px ",
             # h5('..'),
             
             p("...."),
             ),
    
    # #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(align='left',style="text-align: justify;",
        column(width = 6, 
               plotlyOutput('VUELOS.X.ANIO')),

        column(width = 6, h3('...'),
                            p(".....")     
                 
        ) ),
    # #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(style = "border: 4px double blue;",align='center',style="text-align: justify;",

        column(width = 6, h3('....'),
              
               p(".."),
               ),

        column(width = 6,align='center',
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio_vuelos_mes",
                   label = "",
                   choices = c('Todos', 'Domestico', 'Internacional'),
                   selected = 'Todos',
                   status = "success"),
               plotlyOutput('VUELOS.MES')
        ) ),
    # #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
        column(width = 8,align='center',
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio_vuelos_semanal",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = c('Todos', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022','2023'),
                                 selected = 'Todos',
                                 status = "info"),
               plotlyOutput('VUELOS.SEMANAL')
        ),


        column(width = 4, align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
               h3('....'),
               
               p("....")
        ) ) ,
    # #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    fluidRow(style = "border: 4px double blue;",align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
        column(width = 3,h3("....."),
             
               p(".......")
               
        ),
        column(width = 9, align='center',
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio_promDiario",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = c('Todos', 'Domestico', 'Internacional'),
                                 selected = 'Todos',
                                 status = "success"),
               plotlyOutput('PROM.DIARIO')
        ) ),
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    fluidRow(align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
        column(width = 8,     align='center',
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio_empresas",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = c('Todos', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022','2023'),
                                 selected = 'Todos',
                                 status = "info"),
               plotlyOutput('TOP.EMPRESAS')
        ),
        column(width =4, h3('.....'),
            
               p("....")
               
        )  ),
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(style = "border: 4px double blue;",align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
             column(width = 4, h3('......'),
                    p("....."),
                    
                    p("....")
             ),
             column(width = 8,align='center',
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "radio_par_ori_dest",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = c('Todos', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022','2023'),
                                 selected = 'Todos',
                                 status = "info"),
               plotlyOutput('ORI.DEST'))
             ),
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fluidRow(align='center',style="text-align: justify;",
        column(width = 6, align = "center",
               plotlyOutput('MAPITA')
        ),
        column(width=6, align='center', style="text-align: justify;", 
               h3('......'), 
               
               p("......"),
               radioGroupButtons(inputId = "rd_mapa",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = c('Todos', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022','2023'),
                                 selected = 'Todos',
                                 status = "info"),
               sliderInput("slider_mapa", "Seleccionar rango de número de vuelos anuales",
                           min = 0, max = 1100, value = c(300, 500))
               
               
               )),
    
    )



server <- function(input, output) {    

    # NRO VUELOS X ANIO
    output$VUELOS.X.ANIO = renderPlotly({ despegues_x_anio(datos) })
   
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    # NRO VUELOS X MES
    anio_vuelos_x_mes = reactive({ input$radio_vuelos_mes }) #Obtengo el chbox elegido; luego accedo a el usando anio_vuelos_x_mes()
    output$VUELOS.MES= renderPlotly({vuelos_mensuales(datos , anio_vuelos_x_mes() ) }) #Ejecuto la fc para plotear el grafico
    
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    # VUELOS X DIA DE LA SEMANA
    anio_vuelo_semanal = reactive ({ input$ radio_vuelos_semanal})
    output$VUELOS.SEMANAL = renderPlotly({vuelos_semanales(datos , anio_vuelo_semanal() ) }) 
    
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    # PROMEDIO DIARIO DE VUELOS
    tipo_vuelo_promDiario = reactive ({ input$radio_promDiario})
    output$PROM.DIARIO = renderPlotly({promedio_dia(datos, tipo_vuelo_promDiario() ) }) 
    
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    # TOP EMRPESAS
    aerol = reactive ({ input$radio_empresas})
    output$TOP.EMPRESAS = renderPlotly({airlines(datos, aerol() ) }) 
    
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    # PARES ORIGEN-DESTINO
    rd_ori_dest = reactive ({ input$radio_par_ori_dest})
    output$ORI.DEST = renderPlotly({pair_airports(datos , rd_ori_dest() ) }) 
    
    
    # ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    radio_map  = reactive ({ input$rd_mapa})
    limInf = reactive({input$slider_mapa[1]})
    limSup = reactive({input$slider_mapa[2]})
    output$MAPITA = renderPlotly({plot_mapa(provincias, datos , aeropuertos , radio_map(), limInf(), limSup() ) }) 
    
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the log I get:

```
2023-07-26T00:51:38.019300+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Content will use current R environment
2023-07-26T00:51:38.019305+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2023-07-26T00:51:38.019326+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: .libPaths(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library
2023-07-26T00:51:38.024980+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: shiny version: 1.7.4.1
2023-07-26T00:51:38.024991+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: httpuv version: 1.6.11
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025001+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025006+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: knitr version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025044+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: jsonlite version: 1.8.5
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025055+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025060+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: htmltools version: 0.5.5
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025076+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: reticulate version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:38.025207+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2023-07-26T00:51:38.422480+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Starting R with process ID: '34'
2023-07-26T00:51:38.422889+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Shiny application starting ...
2023-07-26T00:51:38.643293+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Warning in install.packages(x[!installed_packages]) :
2023-07-26T00:51:38.643333+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]:   'lib = "/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library"' is not writable
2023-07-26T00:51:38.688922+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Error in install.packages(x[!installed_packages]) : 
2023-07-26T00:51:38.688966+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]:   unable to install packages
2023-07-26T00:51:38.688971+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2023-07-26T00:51:38.688975+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Execution halted
2023-07-26T00:51:38.688980+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Shiny application exiting ...
2023-07-26T00:51:40.722843+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Running on host: 3bdeb9c8ed40
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725578+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725603+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Connect version: 2023.03.0
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725608+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725612+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/trafico_aereo_argentina
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725801+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Using R 4.3.1
2023-07-26T00:51:40.725826+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R
2023-07-26T00:51:40.726155+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Content will use current R environment
2023-07-26T00:51:40.726186+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.726194+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: .libPaths(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730866+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: shiny version: 1.7.4.1
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730883+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: httpuv version: 1.6.11
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730887+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730891+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: knitr version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730898+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: jsonlite version: 1.8.5
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730909+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730927+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: htmltools version: 0.5.5
2023-07-26T00:51:40.730941+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: reticulate version: (none)
2023-07-26T00:51:40.731087+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2023-07-26T00:51:41.114185+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Starting R with process ID: '53'
2023-07-26T00:51:41.114570+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Shiny application starting ...
2023-07-26T00:51:41.185987+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Warning in install.packages(x[!installed_packages]) :
2023-07-26T00:51:41.186023+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]:   'lib = "/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library"' is not writable
2023-07-26T00:51:41.245099+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Error in install.packages(x[!installed_packages]) : 
2023-07-26T00:51:41.245128+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]:   unable to install packages
2023-07-26T00:51:41.245136+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2023-07-26T00:51:41.245142+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Execution halted
2023-07-26T00:51:41.245150+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Shiny application exiting ...
2023-07-26T01:06:42.557234+00:00 shinyapps[9508974]: Container event from container-8434200: stop
```

Comment: Perhaps the `./data` folder is not being shared properly.  Did you try moving the files into `.`?

Comment: I tried to move the data sets into the ```.``` folder *which is the same as the ```.R``` files, with no better luck.

Comment: Have you tried putting simple `library()` calls at the top of your app? I imagine that's what a lot of people do so maybe shinyapp.io installs them for you, if you follow the pattern it's expecting.

Comment: Yeap, I've replaced the install.packages() condition by calling each library in ```library()```. Now I get another error : ```Capturing R dependencies with renv
Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : 
  aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure
Calls: <Anonymous> ... snapshotRenvDependencies -> <Anonymous> -> renv_snapshot_validate_report```

Comment: [This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-deploy-on-shinyapp-io/170160) suggests downgrading the `rsconnect` connect package.  Looking at the GitHub issues and recent commits indicates recent changes to how `renv` gets used.  Are you using `renv`? Are you submitting as a package with a DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: @MichaelDewar downgrading the ```rsconnect``` package solved this for me, much appreciated as I've been struggling with this for a week now!! Please post this as a proper answer so I can mark it as solved by you.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "exit status 1" error in Shiny apps on shinyapps.io can occur due to various reasons. The most common issues are related to resource limitations, file size restrictions, or package dependencies.

In your case, the first thing which comes to my mind is the fact that you upload a 160 MB file without, at least not from what I could find,
changing the maximum upload size.

The default for that is **5 MB**, so in your case this snippet at the beginning
of the server should fix the issue if it is indeed a problem with the size limit.

```
  # Increase the maximum upload size to 160 MB 
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 160*1024^2)
```

If you want a different file size, just change the first value in the term,
or, if you want a little bit of wiggle room, just do 200 or something.
Let me know if this helps. ;)

Comment: Hi @Zearpex, I added your suggestion to the top of the script. It doesn't fix it. I've added the log of the app... is something wrong with the packages, or with the log line ```Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>``` ?

Comment: I've been told that I have to call each library and do not request shiny to install it. When calling each library(), I get the following error   ```Capturing R dependencies with renv
Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : 
  aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure
Calls: <Anonymous> ... snapshotRenvDependencies -> <Anonymous> -> renv_snapshot_validate_report```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two problems.  The first is that you should use simple `library()` calls at the top of the app.  Don't try to install them yourself.  shinyapp.io will automatically take care of that for you.

Secondly, [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-deploy-on-shinyapp-io/170160) suggests downgrading the rsconnect connect package. Recent commits on the rsconnect GitHub show that there have been changes to how they handle `renv`, but I don't really know how you've set up your app.  Try downgrading first.